# How to change className?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I keep div element in my state. I want to change it's `className` in response to `onClick` event. I know I could do it with `event.target.className` but the  code below is only the sample of a biggest application and it's not possible to use it there. As a resultant from `changeClass` function I get

> "TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'className' of object '#'".

So I wonder is there any other way to do it?

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import "./styles/style.css";

    class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          myDiv: [
            <div
              id="firstDiv"
              key={1}
              className={"first"}
              onClick={this.changeClass}
            />
          ]
        };
      }


  changeClass = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return { myDiv: (prevState.myDiv[0].props.className = "second") };
    });
  };


      render() {
        return <div>{this.state.myDiv.map(div => div)}</div>;
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

Comment: You can't change state directly. You have to use `setState` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put your jsx in state. only add className and state and onChangeClass use this.stateState to update className.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles/style.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      className:"first"
    };
  }

  changeClass = () => {
     this.setState({ classNmae: "two" }); 
  };

  render() {
    return <div>
       <div
          id="firstDiv"
          className={this.state.className}
          onClick={this.changeClass}
       />
    </div>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I've read somewhere that it's ok to put components in component state. Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 2):

there's a simpler option try this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles/style.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      className: "first"
    };
  }

  changeClass = () => {
    this.setState({className: "second"});
  };

  render() {
    return <div 
             id="firstDiv"
             className={this.state.className}
             onClick={this.changeClass}>              
           </div>;
   }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Hooks if you use a React version upper than 16.8

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import "./styles/style.css"

const App = () => {
  const [myClass, setMyClass] = useState("first")

  const changeClass = () => {
    setMyClass("second")
  }

  render() {
    return <div 
             id="firstDiv"
             className={myClass}
             onClick={changeClass}>              
           </div>;
   }
}

export default App
```